# Element's CSS, reverts back at the end of page load?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, greasemonkey, roblox

I am trying to change the `position` of

```
<div class="BannerRedesign" id="Banner" style="position: fixed ! important; height: 36px ! important; width: 100% ! important;">
    <div class="BannerCenterContainer" id="NavigationRedesignBannerContainer">
```

(roblox banner element, trying to make it not float)
to `relative` using Greasemonkey, with all privileges enabled. But, every time, at the end of the loading of the document, it reverts to floating.

I even tried appending `bannercentercontainer` to a different element, but I don't know if I did it right...
can you please help me change this to relative position?

I tried:

```
$('#Banner').css('position', 'relative !important')
```

and

```
if ($('#Banner').css('position') == 'fixed') {
$('#Banner').css('position', 'relative')
}
```

, but it just changed back once the page finished loading.

Comment: element is not stubborn. your code is stubborn !!. edit the title and give meaningful title for question

Comment: why are you changing the position css... shouldn't you be changing float:none; ?

Comment: Are you waiting until the DOM is loaded before you run your javascript?

Comment: can't use `important` in inline style

Answer (score 1):

That banner is probably set in the static HTML and periodically reset by AJAX.

One way to fix it is with [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Here is **a complete script** that will work on the code given in the question:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Unfix annoying banner
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#Banner", unFixThePositioning);

function unFixThePositioning (jNode) {
    jNode.css ('position', 'relative');

    //-- Or, for a little extra "Oomph":
    jNode[0].style.setProperty ("position", "relative", "important");

    return true;    //-- Check repeatedly.
}
```