# How to override page styles without using !important, in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that applies styles with either `.css()` or `GM_addStyle()`.  These styles are getting overwritten by the styles that are on the page, causing undesired effects.

I know that I can fix this by using `!important` on all of my styles, but I really don't want to do this. Is there any way to do this w/o using `!important`?

Comment: `.css()` should override everything except `!important` rules. That means, you will probably have to fight `!important` with `!important`.

Comment: can you show me a html/css snippet from the console?

Comment: so you want the Greasemonkey `GM_addStyle()` or `.css()` to have precedence over page CSS right?

Comment: Yes, as far as i can tell there aren't any other !important rules on the page i'm trying it on

Comment: Duplicate of [Overriding !important style using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript) and of [Element's CSS, reverts back at the end of page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14618541/331508).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using `!important` in Greasemonkey scripts and Stylish styles. (It is sometimes misused in regular web pages, but userscripts are different).

`!important` is the only way to override styles set in attributes.  For example, if we want to change this:

```
<div id="annoyingBlock" style="background: red; top: 4em; display: inline block ... Bunch of other styles that we don't want to touch.">
    Look at me!
</div>
```

to have a white background, our userscript must either overwrite that `style` attribute (which can be a right pain on large complex sites and can bust the other inline styles we may still want) or, it must use the `!important` flag, like so:

```
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    #annoyingBlock {                            \
        background:         white !important;   \
    }                                           \
" );
```

This is because [attributes (inline styles) have a higher precedence](http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence) over anything but `!important` styles.

---

---

If your style changes using `.css()` are getting overwritten by the page's javascript, use a technique like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14618898/331508) to combat that.